# trying to use node.js and mysql to connect to different database per user - preferably using a pool

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm fairly new to nodejs, knex, bookshelf etc and am currently developing a web app that would connect to a different mysql database based on which user is logged in.

The first connection works fine, I then log out and in the sign out code I do knex.destroy().
When I go to log back in I get an
    `Unhandled rejection Error: There is no pool defined on the current client`

It seems that knex doesn't recreate a pool once it has been destroyed even if it gets reinitialized.

Has anyone tried this and know how to do it?

I have tried initialising without a database and adding one when the user logs in but the connection doesn't seem to then connect to the database. I've tried instantiating a new connection with the database without destroying the previous, which results in the user using the first user's database. Destroying the connection removes the MySQL connections and even establishes a new connection with the right database but apparently no pool.

From reading it looks like knex wasn't designed to do this but surely there must be a way to instantiate a new connection with a new pool?

I'm using passport-local
code snippets follow

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(email, password, done) {
    new userModel.User({email: email}).fetch().then(function(data) {
      var user = data;
      if(user === null) {
         return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
      } else {
         user = data.toJSON();
         if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
         } else {
             ctrl = new DB();
             ctrl.connect(user.db);
             dbModel = require('../server/models/dbModel');
             return done(null, user);
         }
      }
   });
}));
```

**DB.js**

```
function DB(){

}


DB.prototype.connect = function (db){   
    if (db !== "crm" && db !== null){
        db = "crm-" + db;
    }

    DB.knex = require('knex')({
        client: 'mysql',
        connection:{
            host: 'localhost',  // your host
            user: MYSQL_USR, // your database user
            password: MYSQL_PWD, // your database password
            database: db,
            charset: 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI' //,
    //      debug : true
        }
    });

    DB.bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(DB.knex);
};

DB.prototype.destroy = function (){
    DB.knex.destroy().then(console.log("destroyed"));
};

module.exports = DB;
```

please help!
let me know what other code you may need.

Has anyone ever done this and if so how? Please, I have not had or found any answers.

Comment: Is the number of databases to connect to fixed and known ahead of time?

Comment: What do mean by different databases per user? Like usernames that started with a...m and the other databases is for n...z or do you mean the users model uses one database and the other models use another? Or is all other models using a different database per user?

Comment: each user has a database for their data, when they log in they should be able to access their database.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I got this stripped down version to work. I'm not really familiar with knex, but I created two very simple databases and I was able to connect to both and get simple output.

index.js

```
var DB = require('./DB');

function userConnect(db_name){
    var db = new DB();
    var knex = db.connect(db_name);

    knex.select('color').from('test').then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        knex.destroy();
    });
}

userConnect('db_one');
userConnect('db_two');
```

DB.js

```
function DB(){

}


DB.prototype.connect = function (db){   
    return require('knex')({
        client: 'mysql',
        connection:{
            host: MYSQL_HOST,  // your host
            user: MYSQL_USER, // your database user
            password: MYSQL_PASSWORD, // your database password
            database: db
        }
    });
};

module.exports = DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really what you want to do. What if you have two different users logged in at the same time. Both need to be able to access their connection. Having different databases means you probably should ether turn off pooling all together. In the config you can set `pool: { min: 0, max: 0}`. Or the other way would be you need to hold onto a database for each user currently logged-in and then once the logout or after some time-period you should release the database not destroy it.

You should really think hard before you use a different database for each user. This can make for a bunch of work down the road when you have to migrate 1000's of databases.

Comment: I am thinking of holding a database connection for each user currently logged in. I am not sure if that can be achieved. I haven't looked at this for a while. I thought perhaps putting each new connection into an array or something and finding the right one when a request is made.
The thought process for keeping a database per user is to keep the data separate, for security purposes.

Comment: I agree with @JTWebMan on this one. Multiple databases are going to be difficult to deal with as well as the fact that you can't really do any useful data gathering on separate databases (no joins, etc.). But if you insist I did provide you with a working example above.

Comment: @Peter there are better ways of dealing with security. The reason this is so hard is this is a bad design pattern. You could add user id on each record that is theirs and always filter on user id. It is hard to suggest a better solution without knowing the problem. Maybe you can add to the question what data you want secure. Holding a connection pool for each user means you will have some scaling issues after a few 100 users.

Comment: @HeadCode I have not been able to get your solution working with my code at this point.